# Python: Controling Keyboard and Mouse together in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a GUI using TKinter to collect or get the input from the user (e.g. ABC) and my program will update (copy - e.g. ABC) to a text file in the background when the user clicks the button 'OK'.

Now my second goal is to make it a little bit more complex: instead of getting the input from the user, I would like to get the input from another application (e.g. notepad or a webpage, etc.).

The user will click the selected text (ABC) from another application using 'ctrl + right mouse', then the selected part (e.g. ABC) should be copied directly to the GUI input instead of having the user manually entering it.

Is it possible using Tkinter or could anyone give me some example on how to handle it.

Comment: I am not sure you can do this with tkinter.

Comment: There is Qt designer for python... try that.

Comment: Simply use the clipboard to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with clipboard.